# Show two React Component in IF ELSE condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

In React App.js i have condition if false then show two component if false show third component but i am not able to pass two component if condition is false

```
{ !this.state.imageView ?
              (  <OneComponent/> && <TwoComponent/>)
                 : // else
                  <ThridComponent />
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your two components with a single element.

If you don’t need an additional element, such as a `<div>`, then you can use a fragment for this:

```
{!this.state.imageView
  ? (
    <>
      <OneComponent/>
      <TwoComponent/>
    </>
  )
  : (
    <ThridComponent />
  )
}
```

Note, the above `<>...</>` syntax is shorthand for:

```
{!this.state.imageView
  ? (
    <React.Fragment>
      <OneComponent/>
      <TwoComponent/>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
  : (
    <ThridComponent />
  )
}
```

You can read more about fragments here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: Thank you it helped

Comment: can you help in pass multiple params in and api 
https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/{{section}}/{{sort}}/{{window}}/{{page}}?showViral={{showViral}}&mature={{showMature}}&album_previews={{albumPreviews}}

Comment: using fetch method i mean i click on anchor tag i get section then how can i pass {{section}} again if i click on anchor tag of {{sort}

Comment: @KUMARSUBHAM are you able to post a new question with a code example of what you are trying to achieve? ...and send me the link please

Comment: https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#311b0a17-29d2-48f5-b5cd-09dcc12863f5

Comment: i want to create react app where i can pass all the param of api

Answer (score 0):

JSX needs to return a single element, to return multiple elements you need to wrap it in a `Fragment`, the simplest way is to wrap your elements within `<> ... </>` tags.

Change the `(<OneComponent/> && <TwoComponent/>)` to `<><OneComponent/>  <TwoComponent/> </>` and remove the `&&`

```
{ !this.state.imageView ?
    <>  <OneComponent/>  <TwoComponent/></>
    :
    <ThridComponent />
}
```